# File won't write to disk. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, writetofile

I'm trying to persist an array of objects to file. That has failed. So to test my process, I've tried writing a simple string to file and that hasn't worked either. Below is the code I'm using to test the simple writing of a string to file.

```
    var directoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    var path = directoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(archivePath)
    var checkFile = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    NSLog("Path: %@", path)

    var testString = "Hi my name is ken"
    var error : NSError?
    var written = testString.writeToFile(path, atomically: true, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, error: &error)
    if ( written == false  ) {
        if ((error ) != nil) {
            var errString = error?.localizedDescription
            NSLog( "Fail: %@", errString! )
            var isDir : ObjCBool = false
            var isFile = checkFile.fileExistsAtPath(directoryPath, isDirectory: &isDir)
            if ( isDir ){
                NSLog("The directory %@, exists", directoryPath )
            } else {
                NSLog("The directory %@, does not exist", directoryPath )
            }

        }
    }
```

This is the result from the NSLog statements:

2015-02-25 08:37:29.280 ...App Name... [14596:3911337] Path: /Users/cs/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1747CFD7-5252-4221-AA89-BDEC1A57BA5A/data/Containers/Data/Application/5DC24B8F-A667-4ECD-B7E6-E139E65525E1/Documents/data/appdata.txt
2015-02-25 08:37:29.284 ...App Name... [14596:3911337] Fail: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)
2015-02-25 08:37:29.285 ...App Name... [14596:3911337] The directory /Users/cs/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1747CFD7-5252-4221-AA89-BDEC1A57BA5A/data/Containers/Data/Application/5DC24B8F-A667-4ECD-B7E6-E139E65525E1/Documents, exists

Comment: Verify that you don't have a file exists at that path before writing your content to it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't include the archive path, but I assume it is /data/appdata.txt.

The documents directory exists, but there isn't a /data folder in it, unless you create it.  Trying to write the file to /data/appdata.txt doesn't automatically create the data directory.  Either first create the data directory in the .DocumentzDirectory, or just try saving the file to the root (without the /data/).

Answer (score 0):

```
    var directoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        var path = directoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(archivePath)
        var checkFile = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        NSLog("Path: %@", path)

        var testString = "Hi my name is ken"
        var error : NSError?
    //1. if your archivePath is just a file name with extension
        //remove exist file first
        var canWrite : bool = true
        if (checkFile.fileExistsAtPath(path)) {
           canWrite = checkFile.removeItemAtPath(path, error:&error)
        }

        if (!canWrite) {
           //show alert

           //and return
           return
        }
    //2. if your archivePath is a path with some folder, besure to create if folder does not exist and continue with //1.    

        var written = testString.writeToFil

e(path, atomically: true, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, error: &error)
    if ( written == false  ) {
        if ((error ) != nil) {
            var errString = error?.localizedDescription
            NSLog( "Fail: %@", errString! )
            var isDir : ObjCBool = false
            var isFile = checkFile.fileExistsAtPath(directoryPath, isDirectory: &isDir)
            if ( isDir ){
                NSLog("The directory %@, exists", directoryPath )
            } else {
                NSLog("The directory %@, does not exist", directoryPath )
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. When I can get back to the project I will try this all out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the directory helped, but it turns out, the key to the problem was the array I was writing to disk had dictionaries which contained values that weren't compatible with plists. Array.writeToFile... writes to Plists and if data in the array isn't compatible with a plist, it won't write. I ended up using NSKeyArchiver and NSKeyUnArchiver to handle the writing and reading. Once I used that and handled the directory issue, it all worked. Thanks to all for your suggestions.